# JUNIT 5 report collapsing automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, junit5

When I'm running my tests on JUNIT 5, its report automatically collapses between one parameterized test and another during execution:

[image]

For example, when the 1st Device is running, the run report is opened like that. When the first test finishes and goes to the second run, all these lines collapses and I need to right-click the "TestCases" at the top and click on "Expand All" option.

Not sure if this is clear, I wish I could record a gif, but I'd like to know if there is an option to JUNIT do not collapse the executions automatically, because sometimes I want to follow the execution in real-time and see if any of the tests got an error, and not just at the end of the execution.

Comment: JUnit is just sending out „events“ to your IDE about tests being started and finished. JUnit has no control over how the IDE will animate this stream of events. So I guess this should be a feature request for your IDE vendor.

Comment: got it, thanks for your comment, if you want, reply the question so I can make it as resolved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit is just sending out „events“ to your IDE about tests being started and finished. JUnit has no control over how the IDE will animate this stream of events.

So I recommend that you open a feature request for your IDE vendor.